# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'body' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to debug it, but it is not resolving. Can anyone help me? I am getting the *SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*
I have tried all the possible way but again and again getting either ***TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'body' as it is undefined*** OR ***SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input error.***

Here's my /api/send/route.js code:

```
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    import { Resend } from "resend";
    
    const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);
    const fromEmail = process.env.FROM_EMAIL;
    
    export async function POST(req, _res) {
      const { body } = await req.json();
    
      const { email, subject, message } = body;
      try {
        const data = await resend.emails.send({
          from: fromEmail,
          to: [email],
          subject: subject,
          react: (
            <>
              <h1>{subject}</h1>
<p>Thank you for contancting me!</p>
              <p>new message was submitted:</p>
              <p>{message}</p>
            </>
          ),
        });
    
        return Response.json(data);
      } catch (error) {
        return Response.json({ status: "fail", error });
      }
    }
```

And here's my email section. jsx file code:

```
    /* eslint-disable react/no-unescaped-entities */
    "use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import GitHubIcon from "../../public/images/github.png";
import LinkedInIcon from "../../public/images/linkedin.png";
import DiscordIcon from "../../public/images/discord.png";
import XIcon from "../../public/images/X.png";

const EmailSection = () => {
  const [emailSumitted, setEmailSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      email: e.target.email.value,
      subject: e.target.subject.value,
      message: e.target.message.value,
    };
    const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const endpoint = "/api/send";

    // forming the request for sending data to the server
    const options = {
      method: "POST",

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSONdata,
    };

    const response = await fetch(endpoint, options);
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Message sent.");
      setEmailSubmitted(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section
      id="contact"
      className="grid md:grid-cols-2 my-12 md:my-12 py-24 gap-4 relative"
    >
      {/* <div className='bg-[radial-gradient(ellipse_at_center,_var(--tw-gradient-stops))] from-purple-900 to-transparent rounded-full h-80 w-80 z-0 blur-lg absolute top-3/4 -left-4 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-1/2'></div> */}
      <div className="z-1">
        <h5 className="text-xl font-bold text-white my-2">Let's Connect</h5>
        <p className="text-[#ADB7BE] mb-4 max-w-md">
          {" "}
          Whether it's about the latest tech trends, UI/UX design, or just a
friendly conversation, feel free to reach out!
        </p>
        <div className="socials flex flex-row gap-2">
          <Link href="https://github.com/DiyaVj">
            <Image src={GitHubIcon} className="w-10" alt="Github Icon" />
          </Link>
          <Link href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/diya-vijay/">
            <Image src={LinkedInIcon} className="w-10" alt="LinkedIn Icon" />
          </Link>
          <Link href="https://linktr.ee/Diyavj">
            <Image src={DiscordIcon} className="w-10" alt="Discord Icon" />
          </Link>
          <Link href="https://twitter.com/DiyaVijay6">
            <Image src={XIcon} className="w-10" alt="X Icon" />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {/* Email  */}
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="email"
              className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium"
            >
              Your email
            </label>
            <input
              name="email"
              type="email"
              id="email"
              required
              className="bg-[#18191E] border border-[#33353F] placeholder-[#9CA2A9] text-gray-100 text-sm rounded-lg block with full p-2.5"
              placeholder="example@gmail.com"
            />
          </div>
          {/* Subject  */}
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="subject"
              className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium"
            >
              Subject
            </label>
            <input
              name="subject"
              type="text"
              id="subject"
              required
              className="bg-[#18191E] border border-[#33353F] placeholder-[#9CA2A9] text-gray-100 text-sm rounded-lg block with full p-2.5"
placeholder="Say Hi or anything you would like to..."
            />
          </div>
          {/* message  */}
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="message"
              className="text-white block text-sm mb-2 font-medium"
            >
              Message
            </label>
            <textarea
              name="message"
              id="message"
              className="bg-[#18191E] border border-[#33353F] placeholder-[#9CA2A9] text-gray-100 text-sm rounded-lg block with full p-2.5"
placeholder="Let's talk about..."
            />
          </div>
          {/* button  */}
          <button
            type="submit"
className="bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 to-purple-700 hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-slate-800 hover:to-slate-700 text-white font-medium py-2.5 px-5 rounded-lg w-full"
          >
            Send Message
          </button>
          {emailSumitted && (
            <p className="text-green-500 text-sm mt-2">
Email sent successfully!
            </p>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default EmailSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
const { body } = await req.json();
const { email, subject, message } = body;
```

Do this: (not recommended)

```
const { body } = req;
const { email, subject, message } = body;
```

or do this: (recommended)

```
const { email, subject, message } = req.body;
```